# Redirect to www only works if you omit https://

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm helping a client figuring out a redirect issue on their site.

Basically, everything works the way it should except for one thing.
If you type in example.com (without https) in the browser, the page loads fine.
When typing https://example.com, the page fails.

It's probably some minor issue but I can't figure it out.

This is what they have in Apache config:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Anyone with a good eye that can see what's wrong?

Comment: Why two separate conditions testing the HTTP_HOST?   If the second one is true, then the first one will be true as well.   The second one seems 100% redundant.

Comment: Is your site behind a reverse proxy?   (Is that why you are using X-Forwarded-Proto?)

Comment: They're using AWS Load Balancer so I think that's the reasoning behind X-Forwarded-Proto.

Answer (score 0):

What is the backend?  Is it Drupal, WP or something else?

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

BE SURE TO BACK UP YOUR ORIGINAL APACHE CONFIG FILE FIRST!

Comment: No framework that I'm aware of.